# High memory usage with Aspnet Core + Signalr + EF Core (with Aspnetboilerplate)

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-signalr

I am creating this game server using Aspnetboilerplate, with EFCore, and SignalR. However the server uses around 200MB of memory during startup, and every each call goes up around 2MB of private bytes in IIS. And after the user disconnect, these memory remains and **does not get disposed.**

When there are around 20 users, the private bytes easily goes up to 5GB after 1-2 minutes. I had to set recycling limit to reset the AppPool

I had read on somewhere where EFCore held a lot resource on launch/query, due to navigation property?

is it not suitable to use in Signalr? or we do have a way to manually dispose the allocation upon each call or maybe upon user disconnection?

**Manager class below uses IRepository to query for data via linq

```
...
    [UnitOfWork]
    public class GreenGameHub : AbpHubBase, ITransientDependency
    {
        
        private readonly GreenUserManager _gum;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly GameUserManager _gm;
        private readonly GameItemManager _gi;
        private readonly GreenOrderManager _greenOrderManager;
        private readonly SettingManager _settingManager;
        private readonly GameUserCheckInManager _gameUserCheckInManager;
        private readonly GameFavouriteFriendManager _gameFavouriteFriendManager;
        private readonly GameMissionManager _gameMissionManager;
        private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;

        public GreenGameHub(
            GreenUserManager gum,
            GameUserManager gm,
            GameItemManager gi,
            SettingManager sm,
            IConfiguration config,
            GameUserCheckInManager guci,
            GreenOrderManager gom,
            GameFavouriteFriendManager gffm,
            GameMissionManager gmm,
            IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager
            )
        {
            _gm = gm;
            _gi = gi;
            _gum = gum;
            _settingManager = sm;
            _config = config;
            _gameUserCheckInManager = guci;
            _greenOrderManager = gom;
            _gameFavouriteFriendManager = gffm;
            _gameMissionManager = gmm;
            _unitOfWorkManager = unitOfWorkManager;
        }
        
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User Connected: " + Context.ConnectionId + " / " + Context.GetUserIdOrNull());
            //await Clients.All.SendAsync("OnUserConnected", "A user has connected: " + Context.GetUserIdOrNull());
            await _gm.AddConnectionByGameUserAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["User-Agent"], null);
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
        
        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User Disconnected: "+Context.ConnectionId + " / " + Context.GetUserIdOrNull());
            // unregister user from online list
            await _gm.RemoveConnectionAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["User-Agent"], null);

            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(ex);
        }

        public async Task<int> GetGameSetting()
        {
            //await Clients.All.SendAsync("getSetting", "User GetGameSetting");
            return await _settingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync<int>(AppSettingNames.GA_Maintenance);
        }

        private async Task<GameUser> createNewGameUser(GreenUser greenUser)
        {
            var gu = await _gm.CreateGameUserAsync(greenUser);

            List<GameItem> gameItems = new List<GameItem>();
            var itemIdsSettings = await SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync(AppSettingNames.GA_WelcomeGift);
            var itemIds = itemIdsSettings.Split(",");
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < itemIds.Length; i++)
                {
                    var itemId = Int32.Parse(itemIds.ElementAt(i));
                    gameItems.Add(await _gi.CheckAndGetGameItemAsync(itemId));
                }
                
                var userItemList = await _gm.AddGameItemListToUser(gameItems, gu);
                if (userItemList != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userItemList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var userItem = userItemList[i];
                        await TryConsumeOnReceive(gu.Id, userItem);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Create new item failed: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return gu;
        }

        // LOGIN method
        public virtual async Task<GameUserDto> VerifyGameUserAsync(String shopperId)
        { 
            GreenUser greenUser = await _gum.GetUserByShopperIdAsync(shopperId);
            if(greenUser == null)
            {
                throw new UserFriendlyException("User not found: "+ shopperId);
            }
            
            GameUser gu = await _gm.CheckAndGetGameUserByGreenUserIdAsync(greenUser.Id, false);
            if(gu == null)
            {
                gu = await createNewGameUser(greenUser);
            }
            GameUserDto gudto = ObjectMapper.Map<GameUserDto>(gu);
            gudto.GameUserId = gu.Id;

            //TO-DO summarise on add/minus
            gudto.scoreValue = await this._greenOrderManager.GetSomethingAsync(greenUser);
            await _gm.AddConnectionByGameUserAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["User-Agent"], gu);
            return gudto;
        }
...
```

My startup config for Signalr

```
services.AddSignalR(options =>
            {
                options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                options.EnableDetailedErrors = false;
                //options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
                options.AddFilter(typeof(GameHubFilter));
            }).AddMessagePackProtocol().AddJsonProtocol(o =>
            {
                o.PayloadSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
            });

            services.AddSingleton<GameHubFilter>();

....

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<AbpCommonHub>("/signalr");
                endpoints.MapHub<GreenGameHub>("/signalr-greengame", options =>
                {
                    options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
                    options.TransportSendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                });
            }
```

Great thanks for the help

Comment: Based on your scenario and description its hard to directly point the root cause. Unlike, signalR earlier version this kind of issue can be managed by configuring `DefaultMessageBufferSize` however, in latest version no longer its available. In order to analyze your issue, you ought to check call stack which process consuming most of the memory heap and what restricting object disposal. You can use [`Debug Diag tool`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-a-process-in-iis-636559d3-2f31-71eb-d2ba-75da26ece9d7).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue of high memory by making the hub class a **singleton** during startup.